# Where can I find a list of synonyms and corrected spelling?

Tags: synonym, spelling

Is there a source where I can download a text file that has a large collection of synonyms and correct spellings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the [world list project](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/).